# How to "screenshot" leaflet map to base64 with javascript?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a leaflet map with some lines and some shapes on it. I want to click a button that allows me to "screenshot" what is in the leaflet map and output a base64 encoded representation of the image. How do I/ is there a way to do this?

Comment: use the **CANVAS** to achieve what you desire. but you'll need to draw the entire thing on canvas

Comment: Drawing the entire thing on canvas makes no sense to me as leaflet has lots of different elements. I heard of html2canvas, but not sure if that can do what I expect... If there is something that can "screenshot" and draw it to canvas... that would work.

Comment: can you share your code in question so that we may have a look at it? Also please make a fiddle too for us to experiment with it

Answer (score 1):

It's very complicated. Start by reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas. It boils down to creating a `<foreignObject>` inside a `<svg>`, cloning a part of the DOM inside that `<foreignObject>`, then create a `Blob` for the `<svg>`, get a URL for that blob, load it into a `<img>`, and finally access its pixel info.

When you're done reading, fetch the `<div>` that contains your leaflet map and apply the method described.

AFAIK, there is no Leaflet plugin that implements this technique (yet) - the current print/screenshot plugins use older techniques.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12744765)

Comment: I expanded the answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

There is [leaflet-image](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-image) (demo [currently broken](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-image/issues/80)), which only works for canvas-based layers. Anything HTML (Zoom control, L.DivIcon, attribution etc.) will not show up in the saved image.